What is the Geometrical meaning of this $\text{Var}(t)$? What does it measure?
Let $\text{Var}(t)$ be the total variation of the front at time $t$, defined as
$\text{Var}(t) = \int_0^S \left| \kappa(s,t) \right| \sqrt{x_s^2+y_s^2} ds. \tag{1}$
Reference:- https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Esethian/Papers/sethian.comm_math.85.pdf
What is the Geometrical meaning of this $\text{Var}(t)$? What does it measure?
My attempt:-
Starting with a simple, smooth, closed initial curve $\gamma(0)$ in $\mathbb R^2$, let $\gamma(t)$ be the one parameter
family of curves, where $t ∈[0,∞)$ is time, generated by moving the initial curve along its normal vector field with speed $F$ a given function of the curvature. Let $x(s,t)$ be the position vector which, at
time $t$, parameterizes $\gamma(t)$ by $s, 0≤s ≤S , x(0,t) = x(S ,t).$
I can imagine that $\sqrt{x_s^2+y_s^2} ds$ is the segment length. $\text{Var}(t)$ is the line integral of the scalar function $|\kappa(s,t)|$ along the closed curve $\gamma(t)$. What does it measure? I don't understand.

This has nothing to do with the evolution equation you're looking at in the paper. Just as the integral of mean curvature gives the variation of the volume contained by a closed surface, this integral gives the variation of the area contained by your closed curve.

okay. Thank you. Actually, I was reading the textbook "Level set methods" by J.A Sethian. there was some mentioning of this paper. I refered because of that.
